# AudioToolBox not working since xcode update

Tags: ios, xcode, audio

I have an app that uses audiotoolbox framework to play sounds. It used to work fine but since i updated my xcode to 6.1.1 the sounds don't play.
My code is fairly simple:

## .h

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController < SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, ADBannerViewDelegate > {

SystemSoundID playSound1;

}

-(IBAction)playSound1:(id)sender;
```

## .m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

NSURL *SoundURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"airhorn1" ofType:@"wav"]];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL1, &playSound1);

}

-(IBAction)playSound1:(id)sender{

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(playSound1);
NSLog(@"play this sound");

}
```

I then link the action to the button in the storyboard and when i launch the simulator and tap the button i see the "Play this sound" log but the sound doesn't play. Any idea on how this fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` returns a result code. You should verify that the result of that call is `kAudioServicesNoError`. Depending on the result, you may be able to debug this further.

Documentation on the result codes is available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioServicesNoError).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Where am i supposed to see the result code? I don't see anything in the console... Only the NSLog saying the button has been pressed.

Comment: You are not checking the result. `OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)SoundURL1, &playSound1); ` will do the same. Then check if `status` is `kAudioServicesNoError `

Comment: That code is supposed to make something appear in the console? Because there's still nothing. Sorry if i'm missing something, i'm new to this.